# Why am I getting a Connection Error When Trying to Create a New SQL Server Database?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, visual-studio

In Visual Studio's Server Explorer, I right-clicked Data Connections and selected Create New SQL Server Database.

In the same-named dialog that is then invoked, I entered a ServerName, a New Database Name, accepted the default of Windows authorization, but get this:

[image]

I'm pretty sure I installed MS SQL Server when I installed VS (2019). What is causing this error and what do I need to do to fix it?

Am I not allowed to create a Server Name and must use a specific one? If so, what?

### UPDATE

I'm also getting problems now with MySql. I recently created MySql Databases (they are displaying on the left -- "movies" and "statesdb" and I've got connections to them, as indicated by the green connector icon), but now trying to create a new Database also fails (after I hit the "Test Connection" button):

[image]

### UPDATE 2

I still get the same exact err msg after installing SQL Server Express.

And that's even though I do have a bunch of SQLExpress services running now (the only non-new one is the last one):

[image]

Do I need to use SQL Server Authentication instead of Windows?

Comment: Open `services.msc` and verify sql server is installed and running, you can also see the instance name there.

Comment: That must be it - the only "SQL Server" thing I see in there is a reference to a writer for VSS. So which version of MS SQL Server should I install - simply the latest one, I assume?

Comment: Do you have .\SQLEXPRESS as servername?

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts: No, I did not; make that an answer, and I will mark it as such. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see if you have sql server installed and it’s running, you can open `services.msc` and look for SQL Server. The name in between the brackets is the instance name, I.e.: SQLEXPRESS.

To connect to a localhost instance you simply do `.\instancename` or for SQLEXPRESS: `.\SQLEXPRESS`